# TCL - open a new terminal, do some operations in the opened terminal and close it

Tags: linux, terminal, tcl

How can I open a new terminal from TCL code, do some operations (e.g. ls -l), get the results of those operations and close that terminal?

Does the exec command open a new terminal and all the operations are invoked in the terminal or when I call for example "cd .." with exec, that command has nothing to do with the linux terminal and linux commands, those are just pure tcl commands that have the same name as linux standard commands?

Comment: You are aware that `cd` is a command that should never be executed on its own in a subprocess? The “current directory” is a concept that is process local/inherited on all operating systems (well, maybe not on iOS or Android, but you're not dealing with them).

Comment: It just occurred to me that “open a new terminal” might imply that this is to be done on a remote system. *Is this the case?* If it is, it really changes the nature of the solutions possible.

Comment: One thing you should realize is that on Linux (indeed on all unix), terminals never return the result of what is executed in them. Indeed they often return 0 and prints nothing to stdout. It is shells (bash, ksh, csh, zsh, tclsh) that do things in terminals, the terminals themselves are just GUI. So if you want the result of shell operations the terminal is definitely NOT what you want to launch.

Comment: Thanks, you are right! Therefore I have answered my question as I have done. See please it. :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done my task with this:

```
set cvsUpdStr [exec $pathToCvsInYourSystem -qn upd]
```

It does not open a terminal, but it does the task:

1. executes a command
2. results is being stored in `cvsUpdStr` and can be used later

Also it is possible to use it with `catch` to understand if it was executed correctly or to avoid errors:

```
if {[catch {exec $pathToCvsInYourSystem -qn upd} result]} {puts $result}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want [Expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 2):

Any command you pass to `exec` will be sent to the system to be executed. `exec` does not open a terminal window to do this: it does not need to open a GUI window like a terminal just to interact with the underlying system.

A couple of specific notes about  your example commands:

- parsing the output of `ls` or `ls -l` is not recommended. Suppose you have an odd but valid filename like "foo\nbar". You're better off iterating over the results of Tcl's `glob` command.
- `cd` happens to be a Tcl command.

Comment: On Windows, it might force a terminal to be opened. It depends on what's being used to do the executing.